# What does the てさ in 「忘れててさ」 mean?

Tags: meaning, particles

I was reading [the comic strip titled 「エボラ出血熱の巻」 on スマ町](http://mainichi.jp/sumamachi/news.html?cid=20140902mul00m03001000sc) when I encountered 「忘れててさ」. I've reproduced part of the dialogue here for a bit more context (bold mine)

> てっしー：火達磨さん！宿題手伝いますよ
>   火達磨　：てっしー！助かるッ！実は夏休みの調べ学習**忘れててさ**…
>   てっしー：テーマはエボラ出血熱ですか

I gathered that the second clause is omitted, and that the complete pattern would be 「Ａてさ、Ｂ」. Based on this, I found [this 大辞林 entry on てさ](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%A6%E3%81%95&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_tesa_-010) which says

> 〔接続助詞「て」に間投助詞「さ」の付いたもの。(snip)〕
>   ① 文中で，「て」によって調子を整えつつ，「さ」によって語句を軽く指示し，相手に念を押す意を表す。

I interpreted this definition (likely inaccurately) as

> In mid-sentence, while adjusting the tone with 「て」, lightly indicate the phrase with 「さ」, and expresses emphasis to the person one is talking to.

which frankly sounds quite vague to me, especially the 「調子を整えつつ」 part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret it as follows. The `-て` is a shortened version of `いて`, so it should be `忘れていて`. The `さ` is the usual relaxed sentence ending particle, often used between parts of a sentence to request feedback from the listener.

> ね、僕さ、実はさ、昨日コンビニ行ったらさ、...

So I would translate the sentence as "Y'know, I actually forgot to do my homework..."